# Iterator over row and columns

Tags: python, iterator, raytracing

I am writing a simple raytracer just for fun. I want to iterate over rows, and each row must be an iterator over columns. A strategy I produced is the following:

```
class ViewPlane(object):
    def __init__(self, resolution, pixel_size, gamma):
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.pixel_size = pixel_size
        self.gamma = gamma

    def __iter__(self):

        def genR():
            class IterRow(object):
                def __init__(self, plane, row):
                    self.plane = plane
                    self.row = row

                def __iter__(self):
                    def genC():
                        for column in xrange(self.plane.resolution[1]):
                            origin = (self.plane.pixel_size * 
                                       (column - self.plane.resolution[0] / 2.0 + 0.5)
                                        , 
                                        self.plane.pixel_size *
                                         (self.row - self.plane.resolution[1] / 2.0 + 0.5)
                                        , 
                                        100.0
                                     )
                            yield ( Ray(origin = origin, direction = (0.0,0.0,-1.0)), 
                                    (self.row,column)
                                )
                        return
                    return genC()
                def __str__(self):
                    return "Row iterator on row "+str(self.row)
            for row in xrange(self.resolution[0]):
                yield IterRow(self, row)

        return genR()
```

Briefly stated: `ViewPlane` contains the pixel plane. This class implements `__iter__` which defines and returns a generator function. This generator function yields instances of an internal class `IterRow`, which in turn has a `__iter__` method that returns a generator iterating over the columns.

I personally think that it's difficult to understand, so I was wondering if there's a cleaner strategy to achieve the same result.

Comment: This is from one who isn't seasoned... why `self.resolution = resolution` if `resolution` is already available to the whole class (among others)?

Comment: Can you run pylint on your code. I see for example that you are not using `self.pixel_size`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tshepang: I am using it

Comment: Do you use it is some code you are not showing?

Comment: @Tshepang: it's right there, at the instantiation of Ray. I know, it's not very readable. I am changing it

Comment: I can't find it. Can you paste the line here. I wanna know if I'm missing something (pls be patient).

Comment: @Tshepang, the line is "origin = (self.plane.pixel_size *" (and others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo:
  def __iter__(self):
     def innergen():
        yield something
     return innergen()
```

Is the same as:

```
class Foo:
  def __iter__(self):
     yield something
```

In other words, there is no need to define the generator, just yield the values.

Defining a class inside the method just serves to make things complicated and hard to read. Define the class outside of the method.

Having return at the end of a function doesn't do anything and makes it look like you don't know what you are doing. (I'm not saying that you don't, but whenever you include code with effect it raises a red flag. Did you think it do something?)

Unless you really need to access the data row by row I suggesting flattening the iterator.

Stylistically, I prefer to break expressions up rather then trying to split them across several lines as you've done. I think it produces less clutter.

Here is my resulting code:

```
class ViewPlane(object):
    def __init__(self, resolution, pixel_size, gamma):
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.pixel_size = pixel_size
        self.gamma = gamma

    def __iter__(self):
        for row in xrange(self.resolution[0]):
            for column in xrange(self.resolution[1]):
                origin_x = self.pixel_size * self.resolution[0] / 2.0 + 0.5
                origin_y = self.pixel_size * self.resolution[1] / 2.0 + 0.5
                origin = (origin_x, origin_y, 100)
                ray = Ray(origin = origin, direction = (0.0, 0.0, -1.0) )

                yield ray, (row, column)
```

I'm not familiar enough with RayTracers to know but I question having the iterator over ViewPlane produce Ray objects. An iterator is for producing the contents of the object. Is a really contained inside the ViewPlane? Or should the iterator produce coordinates and let the caller construct the Ray objects?

*EDIT*

Here is a version that doesn't flatten the iterator:

```
class ViewPlane(object):
    def __init__(self, resolution, pixel_size, gamma):
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.pixel_size = pixel_size
        self.gamma = gamma

    def row_iter(self, row):
        for column in xrange(self.resolution[1]):
            origin_x = self.pixel_size * self.resolution[0] / 2.0 + 0.5
            origin_y = self.pixel_size * self.resolution[1] / 2.0 + 0.5
            origin = (origin_x, origin_y, 100)
            ray = Ray(origin = origin, direction = (0.0, 0.0, -1.0) )

            yield ray, (row, column)

    def __iter__(self):
        for row in xrange(self.resolution[0]):
            yield self.row_iter(row)
```

Comment: well, there are many things to be said. Thank you for your precious feedback. I'll answer you point by point.

Comment: `Defining a class inside the method just serves to make things complicated and hard to read. Define the class outside of the method.`. Agreed. I wanted to push the limit with that code in order to stress my understanding of closures and the general feeling. It's not production code, it's *let's see what happens* code.

Comment: `Having return at the end of a function doesn't do anything and makes it look like you don't know what you are doing`. That return was supposed to be a raise StopIteration, and I just didn't change it before posting. I wasn't concerned with that, but you are right that both (return or raising) are useless in that context.

Comment: `Unless you really need to access the data row by row I suggesting flattening the iterator.` I need to iterate by row because I render by row, and at each completed row I refresh the GUI. It's easier to roll over the rows, and inside that, roll over the columns. I may also flatten, roll over the pixels and refresh at each new row, but as I said, I'm stressing my knowledge for fun and profit. I wouldn't write that code in production, ever.

Comment: @Stefano Borini, why are you asking for a code review on push your limit code? The whole point of a code review is for helping make it production ready

Comment: `Stylistically, I prefer to break expressions up rather then trying to split them across several lines as you've done. I think it produces less clutter.` Agreed. It's much more readable.

Comment: `I'm not familiar enough with RayTracers to know but I question having the iterator over ViewPlane produce Ray objects.` I am porting to python a design from a book (ISBN: 978-1-56881-272-4). Code is available in C++ under GPL, but again, my objective is to tinker. I tend to follow the book, as introducing variations may make more difficult working on the code in the next chapters.

Comment: @Winston : I assumed code review SE was to comment on snippets, not to rework for production ready.

Comment: One comment though: your design yields a continuous stream of Ray instances, not a continuous stream of Rows. I want to iterate on rows first, and then iterate on pixels on each row next. In other words, you need an intermediate Row object which is an explicit class. You can't obtain the same effect without such class but only through smart use of functions and generators, can you ?

Comment: @Stefano, its just that your code works and you know its not the best way of writing, what did you hope to get out of asking for code review?

Comment: @Stefano, I've added a version which doesn't flatten the iterator and also doesn't introduce a new class.

Comment: @Winston: that's very, very nice. I guess I will have to study again  generators. I seldom use them. Thanks.